# How I should testing Django views with unique slug

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I try write tests.py to my views.

I have issue with write a good test to view with slug.

*views.py:*

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'post': post}
    template = 'post/post_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Url looks like : post/slug_name, and slug is unique for every post.

I try:

*tests.py*

```
class PostDetailTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_post_detail_(self):
        test = Post(title='poost', description="posting", category="letstest", slug='django')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('board_detail', args=(self.slug,)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

*Run test error:*

```
    response = self.client.get(reverse('post_detail', args=(self.slug,
AttributeError: 'PostDetailTestCase' object has no attribute 'slug'
```

How I should repair it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In tests.py `self` currently refers to the class `PostDetailTestCase` and that class has no slug. You've almost created a post in the db that django can access.

What you need to do however is to use the following. You need to use the objects.create method in the following way.

```
test = Post.objects.create(
    title='poost', 
    description="posting", 
    category="letstest", 
    slug='django'
)
```

If you then replace self with test things should work out.

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('board_detail', args=(test.slug,)))
```

Comment: Mate, Thanks!. It was simply and beauty. "Ran tests - OK" . I forgot about .objects.